# Coinbase [List Transactions Call] returning 404 Error

Tags: api, get, postman, coinbase-api

Struggling with verifying Coinbase API calls in Postman.

I'm able to make the following call in Postman successfully:

```
GET https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/:account_id
```

But when i do the next one:

```
GET https://api.coinbase.com/v2/accounts/:account_id/transactions
```

it returns the following error:

```
 {
     "errors": [
         {
             "id": "not_found",
             "message": "Not found"
         }
     ]
 }
```

I am a complete beginner. If any additional information is required please let me know. Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been stuck on this for several days.

Comment: Hi, please avoid screenshots and show us some code instead of links (for the sake of concision and clarity)

Comment: Apologies. The only error code provided is in the post. I've deleted the screenshots for concision.

Comment: Yup, my comment was about the very first version of your post :) This version is way cleaner.

Comment: Were you able to find an answer to this or is the resource just not available?